# For ExoPlayer in Jetpack Compose, the player shows a black screen after pausing and resuming the app for non-looping videos

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

I have a screen that has a player with a video that plays once (so it doesn't loop). After the video finished playing, the player keeps showing the last frame, which is what I want. However, if the video finished playing and I turn the screen off and on, then the player shows a black screen. What I want, is that the player keeps showing the last frame. Is this possible? This issue also persists if the non-looping video hasn't finished playing yet.

It's important to note that this issue doesn't exist for looping videos.

There is a lot of documentation about the lifecycle of the player in regular Android, but none for Compose. I could only find articles online about a Compose version, where the player is released in `onDispose`.

I have a Jetpack Compose implementation of ExoPlayer using AndroidView (since there is no native support yet). Here it is:

```
@Composable
fun VideoLayout(@RawRes rawResource: Int) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(rawResource)
    val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri)
    val exoPlayer = remember(context, mediaItem) {
        ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
            addMediaItem(mediaItem)
            prepare()
            play()
            repeatMode = REPEAT_MODE_OFF
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(exoPlayer) { onDispose { exoPlayer.release() } }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        factory = {
            StyledPlayerView(it).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
                resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_ZOOM
                useController = false
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution? in my case all videos starts with black screen for 0.3 sec

Comment: @AlexeySimchenko Unfortunately still no solution. But I did find this Exoplayer Compose implementation on GitHub that uses `rememberSaveable` with a custom Saver. This might solve it, but I haven't tried it yet. https://github.com/mdpearce/vermilion/blob/f0e229af70ddcd9b10985dfe46c18c35a54708a4/ui/src/main/java/com/neaniesoft/vermilion/ui/videos/exoplayer/ExoPlayer.kt#L58

Comment: I found solution and wanted to publish it here but my project ended and I am busy looking for new job. But I will see what I did to solve this and will publish it shortly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same black screen at the start of a video and I solved it by creating `ExoPlayer` in my `viewModel` before using and passing into composable function that uses it and releasing `exoPlayer?.release()` after using `exoPlayer`.

In my case I needed to show some short looped tutorial, so I didn't want to have all the time a created `ExoPlayer`, so when user presses a tutorial button - a player is created and then passed to composable function to play it. When user closes a tutorial - a player is released in `viewModel`.

So main idea is to move `ExoPlayer` out of the function that uses it to give more time for a player to prepare to work

Comment: The black screen in the beginning is something else?

I added a listener to check if the video is buffering and if it's buffering I'm showing a loading indicator
Sorry for bad formatting in comments...


val isBuffering = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

addListener(object : Player.Listener {
override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                        super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
                        isBuffering.value = playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING
}})


if (isBuffering.value) {
 Loading()
}

Comment: @latsson I had a black screen only for .5 sec, so, no need to show loading indicator. In my case I had a task to show a loop video immediately - without a black screen, loading indicator or something else